# Transit Visa in Kuala Lumpur

Tags: visas, transit, kuala-lumpur

I have an Indian passport and I am travelling from New Delhi, India to San Francisco, USA and have a layover of 3hrs30 mins in Kuala Lumpur International Airport. I would have to change terminals and I guess also require a transit visa. Can the transit visa be applied before or can I get it at the airport itself? How long will the entire process take to collect baggage, clear customs and check in again?

Thanks

Comment: Can I know the incoming and outgoing terminal?

Comment: Is this on one ticket, or do you have separate tickets Delhi-KL and KL-SFO?

Comment: If its one ticket, its more than enough. I had transited with less than one hour connection (international-international)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are eligible for a transit without visa, as you are going to the USA and will be having a valid US visa.

Details:
http://www.lcct.com.my/help/visa-and-permits/transit-visa/

However, I don't think you have booked the flight in single ticket. KLIA2 is only for low cost carriers like Air asia. AFAIK, Air asia doesn't connect to carries which departs to USA in KLIA. If you have booked seperate tickets, you will miss the second flight if first flight is delayed.

Just tips to get there fast.

- Keep the documents proper and rush to the immigration as soon as flight lands.
- Take the KLIA express train to reach from KLIA2 to KLIA1 (where your US flight is taking off)
- It will take 5 minutes to reach there.
- Checkin and collect boarding pass, rush to immigration.
- You can use business class lane, which is shorter, if you have less than 1.5 hours left and explain situation.
- Gates close usually 30 minutes before. There will be security check before the gate also. Count the time for that.

Happy journey. In my opinion, 3:30 is a very short time to do this. I wouldn't count on it. Change the ticket to an earlier time if you can.

Update: I am not sure whether transit visa is available for people not using Malaysian airlines or Air Asia. I suggest to take a E-Visa online (NOT E-NTRI), to avoid any confusion or problems, especially since you don't have much time.

Comment: Please do not post comments for why you did an edit. In the edit page there is a field for what and the reason to edit.